# TypeScript: Last tuple element does not receive type parameters

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to write type definitions for an existing http handler library. I cannot change the API.

```
// Callback function passed to handlers & middleware.
type NextFn<Res> = (err?: Error|null, res?: Res) => void;

// Note: the res parameter is always null.
type Middleware<Req, Res> = (req: Req, res: Res, next: NextFn<Res>) => void;

// A function called after all the middleware.
type Handler<Req, Res> = (req: Req, next: NextFn<Res>) => void;

// A chain a set of middleware functions with a handler function at the end.
type Chain<Req, Res> = [...Middleware<Req, Res>[], Handler<Req, Res>];

const chain: Chain<any, any> = [
    // middleware
    (req, _, next) => {},

    // middleware
    (req, _, next) => {}

    // handler: why am I getting no-explit-any errors here?
    (req, next) => {}
];
```

The last `Handler` element in the array always complains with no-explit-any errors.
Why is TypeScript not able to infer the parameter types for the `Handler`? Is there way to write this so that it works?

**Note:** I've tried replacing the spread in the `Chain` type with overloads, but that didn't work either:

```
type Chain<Req, Res> = [Handler<Req, Res>]
                     | [Middleware<Req, Res>, Handler<Req, Res>]
                     | [Middleware<Req, Res>, Middleware<Req, Res>, Handler<Req, Res>];
```

Comment: because the compiler doesn't understand whether `(x, y) => {}` is a `Handler` or a `Middleware` because [functions with fewer parameters are assignable to functions with more parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions) and so it's having a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: But it knows the last element should be a `Handler`.

Comment: The compiler isn't smart like a human being, so presumably it is doing some heuristic like inferring each element's type from left to right, and at each position it is trying to match either `Handler` or `Middleware` before moving on the the next one.  If that is successful (e.g., you annotate things) then it presumably checks to make sure it matches the type.  This is just a guess though, so I won't post an answer until and unless I can get something more authortitative

Comment: So far all I can find is that I have noticed that the compiler can't do contextual typing properly for unions-of-tuples (which is very similar to the leading-rest version), in [microsoft/TypeScript#42987](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42987), but it's not an explanation for the behavior.

Comment: So at this point I might just file an issue in the GitHub repo (although if you want to do it instead be my guest), using [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9JQ3m) as a repro.  Not sure.

Comment: @jcalz I feel like you're in a better position to describe the problem in the issue. Tag me in it though, my username is icholy on github.